Which version is long term support version for Hibernate ORM version 5? 5.3 or 5.6?
Our Hibernate ORM version is 5.5, but 5.5 is EOL now, we want change to another Non-EOL version, seems only 5.3 and 5.6 support JAVA 8, both 5.3 and 5.6 are limited-support version, the recent update on version 5.3 at 2024-02-08, but the recent update on version 5.6 at 2023-02-06, not sure which version will EOL firstly.
Which version we can select?
